# Problem in Document library in O365 Sharepoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online

I am using Office 365 and creating an Sharepoint 2013 Online website. I am trying something simple:

1. Create a document library
2. Go to the settings and enable content type selection
3. Now when I click on "new" in document library I am getting only upload option. Rhere is no option for creating a document,excel etc.

Answer (score 0):

When you enable the setting for content types, you get rid of that option.  You either need to set up templates for your content types to match what you need, or disable the selection of content types for the library.